# airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Use keyword arguments when initializing operators

Tags: airflow

I am using Airflow version of 1.9.2 with Python 2.7 in Ubuntu. I tried to inherit from `ParentOperator` class which works fine itself and to create a class called `ChildOperator`. But when I create a `ChildOperator` instance, I think some keyword arguments are missing or messed up here and I am getting this error:

> airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Use keyword arguments when
>   initializing operators

Here is a simplified example:

```
class ParentOperator(BaseOperator, SkipMixin):

    @apply_defaults
    def __init__(self,
             conn_id,
             object,
             args={},
             s3_conn_id=None,
             s3_key=None,
             s3_bucket=None,
             fields=None,
             *args,
             **kwargs
             ):

        super(ParentOperator, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        ...


class ChildOperator(ParentOperator):

    @apply_defaults
    def __init__(self,
             conn_id,
             object,
             args={},
             s3_conn_id=None,
             s3_key=None,
             s3_bucket=None,
             fields=None,
             *args,
             **kwargs
             ):

        args=...
        super(ChildOperator, self).__init__(
            conn_id,
            object,
            args=args,
            s3_conn_id=s3_conn_id,
            s3_key=s3_key,
            s3_bucket=s3_bucket,
            fields=fields,
            *args,
            **kwargs
        )

...

myobjc = ChildOperator(
    conn_id="my_default",
    object=table,
    args={},
    s3_conn_id='s3_postgres_dump',
    s3_key=s3_key,
    s3_bucket=s3_bucket,
    dag=dag,
    task_id="task1"
)
```

Any idea what is causing this error? Is this more of a Python specific issue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`__init__` function of `ChildOperator` needs to have all keyword parameters like the following (for the first two parameters of `conn_id` and `object`):

```
super(ChildOperator, self).__init__(
        conn_id=conn_id,
        object=object,
        args=args,
        s3_conn_id=s3_conn_id,
        s3_key=s3_key,
        s3_bucket=s3_bucket,
        fields=fields,
        *args,
        **kwargs
)
```